# Windows 8 keeps prompting to change expired password

Tags: windows-8, passwords, windows-server-2003, active-directory

I am a volunteer doing tech support for a local school.  One of the teachers tried to log in today and got a message that his password had expired and must be changed.  That's expected, since our domain does require password changes.

However, he tried changing his password, but each time just went right back to the "your password has expired and must be changed" message.

As a temporary measure, because he needed to get in for class, I disabled password expiration for his account.  However, I do want to re-enable it (even though I personally don't think it is necessary) because our official policy does say that passwords must be changed regularly.

What could be causing this issue?  What is the proper way to fix it?

If it matters, the client computer is running Windows 8 Pro, and the server is on Windows Server 2003 (hopefully replacing with 2012 R2 soon, and redoing the entire system, but I still need an answer to this question).

Comment: Have you checked for a virus?

Comment: There could be many reasons for this, and without more specifics it's impossible to say for sure.  Did you reboot the computer once and ensure it was communicating on the Domain properly?  Anything related in the Event Logs?  Did you try (re)setting the users password for them to a known phrase (as the server), and then set it to force them to change it again next time?

Comment: @techie007 Thanks for the ideas.  I will check the event log when I go back there later.